# Request.UrlReferrer returns only google.com not the whole keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to capture the keywords that user enter in search engine to visit my website, Issue is that when I use Request.UrlReferrer it returns me only google.com and not returns me the whole url string that contains keywords seperated by hyphen. How can I get the keywords?

Comment: Answered [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/59794/1060). To summarize: this is impossible.

Comment: thanks Anton Gogolev! is there any other way to do that like api's or something else?

Answer (score -2):

You could use `Request.Url` to get the full URL or `Request.QueryString` to get a collection of query strings from the URL.

You can specify which querystring you want to retrieve like so:

```
Request.Querystring["NameOfQueryStringHere"]
```

I think that for google the querystring name for search terms is "q", so try:

```
Request.Querystring["q"]
```

Comment: Request.Url will return me url of my current page. I need complete url of previous page that is google including all the keywords searched.